# Flutter IAP not showing on TestFlight

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am adding IAP on my flutter app its working fine on the play store. But now on Appstore, I have the following documentation I have added products on IAP on App store, and the status is ready to submit. But the issue is when I upload the build on a test flight and install it on my device it's showing my product is not found and also the status of the product is still ready to submit.

[image]

Do I need to upload it on production to test this? Because I have already enabled In-App Purchase on capabilities also and follow all steps but still I cant find IAP products on my app it still shows my products not found.

Comment: kindly update all the field in app purchases. Missing Meta data means some info is not enterned.

Comment: Check the email of your apple account, it must have been mail that what is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please first check on Agreements you have accepted all agreements, banking, and tax info filled. Because if IAP is not showing in the list its means you have something missed.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have a new agreement and need to add this info. After few hours my app starts showing products Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This just means that you are missing some metadata thats required for IAP in app store. Do check the official documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Create a sandbox tester account](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev8b997bee1) to be able to test IAP before releasing the app.

Comment: Done but its not asking for any test account or something its not showing my IAP products on app.

Comment: check out this [link](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203809008-iOS-How-to-Test-In-App-Purchases-in-Your-App) to make sure you are testing correctly using sandbox